# Canvas items not initiating (or clickable)

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I've inherited a seasonal advent calendar (http://i-uat.myfamilyclub.co.uk/adventcalendar/).

The problem I'm having is that the items are not clickable/not initiating.  I've worked out that it's the JS but I can't find the error. What am I missing?

JavaScript:

```
 var colors;
 var mainSpriteImage;
 var elementsSpritesheet;
 var elementFrames;
 var revealSpritesheet;
 var tempPresent;

 var filenames;

 var mainSpritesReady = false;
 var revealSpriteReady = false;
 var numbers = new Array();
 var circles = new Array();

 var popupElement = document.getElementById("popupHolder");
 var popupBack = document.getElementById("popupBackground");
 var popupText = document.getElementById("popupText");
 var popup = new Popup();

 //launch the app
 function go() {

  createjs.CSSPlugin.install(createjs.Tween);
  createjs.CSSPlugin.cssSuffixMap = {top: "%", opacity: ""};
  setup();
  loadAssets();
 }

 function setup() {
  colors = getColors();
 }

 function loadAssets() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.onload = mainSpritesLoaded;
  img.src = "assets/myFamilyClubSprites.png";

  var reveal = document.createElement("img");
  reveal.onload = revealSpriteLoaded;
  reveal.src = "assets/circle_reveal_transparent_2013.png";

 }

 function assetsLoaded() {
  if (mainSpritesReady && revealSpriteReady) {
   createGraphics();
  }
 }

 function mainSpritesLoaded(event) {
  mainSpriteImage = event.target;
  elementFrames = createFrames();
  createMainSpritesheet(mainSpriteImage);
  mainSpritesReady = true;
  assetsLoaded();
 }

 function revealSpriteLoaded(event) {
  createRevealAnimation(event.target);
  revealSpriteReady = true;
  assetsLoaded();
 }


 function createGraphics() {
  var titleCanvas = document.getElementById("titleCanvas");
  var titleAnim = new TitleAnim(titleCanvas);

  if (!mobile) {
   titleAnim.animateIn();
  }


  var holder = document.getElementById("linksHolder");

  var circleSize = 107;
  for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {

   var circle = new Circle(colors[i], circleSize, i + 1, filenames[i], prizeImages[i], links[i]);

   var tempCanvas = holder.appendChild(circle.getCanvas());
   tempCanvas.id = "c" + i;
   tempCanvas.className = "circleCanvas";

   circle.animateIn(i * 10 + 600);
   circles.push(circle);
  }


  var starCanvas = document.getElementById("starLink");
  var star = new Star(starCanvas, mainSpriteImage, elementFrames[10], elementFrames[11]);
  if (!mobile) {
   star.animateIn(1000);
  }


 }


 function createRevealAnimation(image) {
  var data = {
   images: [image],
   frames: {width: 120, height: 120, count: 16, regX: 60, regY: 60},
   animations: { open: [0, 15] }
  }

  revealSpritesheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(data);
 }

 function disableCircles() {
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
   circles[i].removeMouseListeners();
  }
 }
 function enableCircles() {
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
   circles[i].addMouseListeners();
  }
 }

 //title anim
 function TitleAnim(targetCanvas) {
  var canvas = targetCanvas;
  var stage;
  var bmpMyFamilyClub = new createjs.Bitmap(mainSpriteImage);
  var bmpAdventCalendar = new createjs.Bitmap(mainSpriteImage);
  var bmpText = new createjs.Bitmap(mainSpriteImage);

  var targetY1 = 23;
  var targetY2 = 60;
  var targetY3 = 160;


  function init() {
   bmpMyFamilyClub.sourceRect = elementFrames[12];
   bmpMyFamilyClub.regX = Math.floor(elementFrames[12].width * .5);


   bmpAdventCalendar.sourceRect = elementFrames[13];
   bmpAdventCalendar.regX = Math.floor(elementFrames[13].width * .5);

   bmpText.sourceRect = elementFrames[14];
   bmpText.regX = Math.floor(elementFrames[14].width * .5);


   canvas.width = bmpText.sourceRect.width;
   canvas.height = 200;
    canvas.width = 650;

   var centerX = Math.floor(canvas.width * .5);

   stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);


   bmpMyFamilyClub.x = centerX;
   bmpMyFamilyClub.y = targetY1;
   bmpAdventCalendar.x = centerX;
   bmpAdventCalendar.y = targetY2;
   bmpText.x = centerX;
   bmpText.y = targetY3;

   bmpAdventCalendar.alpha = 1;


   if (!mobile) {
    bmpAdventCalendar.y = -100;
    bmpMyFamilyClub.visible = 0;
    bmpText.alpha = 0;

   }


   stage.addChild(bmpMyFamilyClub);
   stage.addChild(bmpAdventCalendar);
   stage.addChild(bmpText);

   stage.update();
  }

  function tick() {
   stage.update();
  }

  init();

  this.animateIn = function () {
   /*  createjs.Ticker.addListener(tick);
    circle.scaleX=circle.scaleY=0;

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
    createjs.Tween.get(circle).wait(delay).to({alpha:1,scaleX:1, scaleY:1},200,createjs.Ease.backOut);
    createjs.Tween.get(container).wait(delay+40).to({alpha:1,scaleX:1, scaleY:1},600,createjs.Ease.backOut).call(this.animInComplete,null,this);
    */
   createjs.Ticker.addListener(tick);
   createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);

   createjs.Tween.get(bmpAdventCalendar).wait(100).to({alpha: 1, y: targetY2}, 300, createjs.Ease.backOut).call(this.animComplete, null, this);
   createjs.Tween.get(bmpMyFamilyClub).wait(300).call(this.test, null, this);

   createjs.Tween.get(bmpText).wait(400).to({alpha: 1}, 1000);
  }

  this.test = function () {
   bmpMyFamilyClub.visible = true;
   createjs.Tween.get(bmpMyFamilyClub).wait(0).to({alpha: 1, y: targetY1}, 400, createjs.Ease.cubicOut);
  }

  this.animComplete = function () {
  }

 }


 //Circle Object
 function Circle(color, size, number, prizeThumb, prizeImageLink, outLink) {

  var canvas;
  var stage;
  var circle;
  var container = new createjs.Container();
  var revealAnim;
  var cf;
  var backBmp;
  var border;
  var active = false;
  var enabled = true;


  function init() {
   canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
   canvas.width = canvas.height = size * 1.1;

   stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
   stage.enableMouseOver(50);

   circle = new createjs.Shape();
   circle.graphics.beginFill(color);
   circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, Math.floor(size * .5));


   circle.x = circle.y = Math.floor(canvas.width * .5);

   border = new createjs.Shape();
   border.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2);
   border.graphics.beginStroke("#bcecfd");
   border.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, Math.floor(size * .5));

   border.x = border.y = Math.floor(canvas.width * .5);


   if (!mobile) {
    revealAnim = new createjs.BitmapAnimation(revealSpritesheet);
    revealAnim.gotoAndStop("open");
    revealAnim.x = revealAnim.y = circle.x;
    revealAnim.rotation = Math.random() * 360;
    cf = new createjs.ColorFilter(0, 0, 0, 1, hexToR(color), hexToG(color), hexToB(color), 0);
    revealAnim.filters = [cf];
    revealAnim.cache(-60, -60, 120, 120);
    revealAnim.updateCache();

   }

   if (prizeThumb != null && prizeThumb != "") {
    backBmp = new createjs.Bitmap(prizeThumb);
    backBmp.image.onload = onBackgroundLoaded;
    backBmp.regX = backBmp.regY = 53;
    backBmp.x = backBmp.y = circle.x;
    if (prizeImageLink == null) {

     backBmp.alpha = .4;
    }
    active = true;
   }


   stage.addChild(circle);


   var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
   if (randNum > 9)randNum = 9;

   container = numbers[number];
   container.x = Math.floor(circle.x);
   container.y = Math.floor(circle.y);


   if (!mobile) {
    circle.scaleX = circle.scaleY = 0;
    container.scaleX = container.scaleY = 0;
    container.alpha = 0;

    if (active) {
     circle.onMouseOver = handleMouseEvents;
     circle.onMouseOut = handleMouseEvents;
    }


   }

   stage.addChild(container);
   stage.update();

   if (active) {
    circle.onClick = onCircleClick;
   }


  }

  function onBackgroundLoaded() {
   stage.update();
  }

  function handleMouseEvents(event) {
   if (!enabled) return;
   switch (event.type) {
    case "onMouseOver":
     document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
     circle.alpha = .8;
     break;
    case "onMouseOut":
     document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
     circle.alpha = 1;
     break;
   }
   stage.update();

  }


  function onCircleClick() {

   if (backBmp == undefined) return;

   backBmp.mask = circle;
   stage.addChild(backBmp);

   stage.addChild(border);

   stage.removeChild(circle);
   stage.removeChild(number);

   if (mobile) {
    stage.update();
    if (prizeImageLink != null) {
     popup.open(prizeImageLink, outLink);
    }

   } else {
    stage.addChild(revealAnim);
    createjs.Ticker.addListener(revealTickHandler);
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(50);

    revealAnim.gotoAndPlay("open");
    revealAnim.onAnimationEnd = onRevealEnd;
   }

   if (prizeImageLink != null) {
    backBmp.onMouseOver = handleMouseEvents;
    backBmp.onMouseOut = handleMouseEvents;
    backBmp.onClick = onPrizeThumbClick;
   }


  }

  function onPrizeThumbClick() {
   if (prizeImageLink == null)return;
   popup.open(prizeImageLink, outLink);
  }

  function onRevealEnd() {
   revealAnim.stop();
   revealAnim.visible = false;
   createjs.Ticker.removeListener(revealTickHandler);
   if (prizeImageLink == null)return;
   popup.open(prizeImageLink, outLink);
  }

  function tick() {
   stage.update();
  }

  function revealTickHandler() {
   revealAnim.updateCache();
   stage.update();
  }


  init();

  this.getCanvas = function () {
   // var
   return canvas;
  }

  this.animateIn = function (delay) {
   if (mobile) {
    if (active && prizeImageLink == null) {
     onCircleClick();
    }

    return;
   }
   createjs.Ticker.addListener(tick);
   circle.scaleX = circle.scaleY = 0;

   createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
   createjs.Tween.get(circle).wait(delay).to({alpha: 1, scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1}, 200, createjs.Ease.backOut);
   createjs.Tween.get(container).wait(delay + 40).to({alpha: 1, scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1}, 600, createjs.Ease.backOut).call(this.animInComplete, null, this);

  }
  this.animInComplete = function () {

   createjs.Ticker.removeListener(tick);
   if (prizeImageLink == null) {
    onCircleClick();
   }
  }

  this.removeMouseListeners = function () {
   enabled = false;
   document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
  }

  this.addMouseListeners = function () {
   enabled = true;
  }
 }

 function Star(canvas, image, starRect, textRect) {
  var canvas = canvas;
  var stage;
  var starBmp;
  var textBmp;

  function init() {

   starBmp = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
   starBmp.sourceRect = starRect;
   starBmp.regX = Math.floor(starRect.width * .5);
   starBmp.regY = Math.floor(starRect.height * .5);

   textBmp = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
   textBmp.sourceRect = textRect;
   textBmp.regX = Math.floor(textRect.width * .5 + 3);
   textBmp.regY = Math.floor(textRect.height * .5);


   canvas.width = starBmp.sourceRect.width;
   canvas.height = starBmp.sourceRect.height;


   textBmp.x = starBmp.x = Math.floor(starRect.width * .5);
   textBmp.y = starBmp.y = Math.floor(starRect.height * .5);
   stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

   stage.addChild(starBmp);
   stage.addChild(textBmp);


   if (!mobile) {
    starBmp.scaleX = starBmp.scaleY = 0;
    textBmp.scaleX = textBmp.scaleY = 0;
    stage.enableMouseOver(50);
   }
   stage.update();


  }

  function handleMouseEvents(event) {
   switch (event.type) {
    case "onMouseOver":
     createjs.Ticker.addListener(tick);
     document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
     starBmp.scaleX = starBmp.scaleY = 1;
     createjs.Tween.removeTweens(starBmp);
     createjs.Tween.get(starBmp).to({alpha: 1, scaleX: 1.05, scaleY: 1.05}, 10, createjs.Ease.quartOut).call(hoverAnimComplete, null, this);
     break;
    case "onMouseOut":
     createjs.Ticker.addListener(tick);
     document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
     createjs.Tween.removeTweens(starBmp);
     createjs.Tween.get(starBmp).to({alpha: 1, scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1}, 30, createjs.Ease.quartOut).call(hoverAnimComplete, null, this);
     break;
    case "onClick":
     window.location.href = prizeLink;
     break;
   }
   stage.update();
  }

  function hoverAnimComplete() {
   createjs.Ticker.removeListener(tick);
  }

  function tick() {
   stage.update();
  }

  init();

  this.animateIn = function (delay) {
   createjs.Ticker.addListener(tick);

   createjs.Tween.get(starBmp).wait(delay).to({alpha: 1, scaleX: .95, scaleY: .95}, 200, createjs.Ease.backOut);
   createjs.Tween.get(textBmp).wait(delay + 50).to({alpha: 1, scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1}, 250, createjs.Ease.backOut).call(this.animInComplete, null, this);
  }

  this.animInComplete = function () {

   stage.onMouseOver = handleMouseEvents;
   stage.onMouseOut = handleMouseEvents;
   stage.onClick = handleMouseEvents;
   createjs.Ticker.removeListener(tick);
  }
 }


 function Popup() {
  var stage;
  var canvas;
  var bitmap;
  var mask;
  var border;
  var link;
  var holder;
  var background;
  var btn;
  var textBackground = new createjs.Shape();
  var description;

  function init() {


   holder = document.getElementById("popupHolder");


   canvas = document.getElementById("popup");
   canvas.width = 640;
   canvas.height = 460;
   stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
   stage.enableMouseOver(50);

   bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap();
   mask = new createjs.Shape();
   border = new createjs.Shape();

   bitmap.mask = mask;
   background = document.getElementById("popupBackground");


   btn = new createjs.Bitmap("images/prizeR.png");
   btn.regX = 150;

   bitmap.onClick = openLink;
   bitmap.onMouseOver = handleMouseEvents;
   bitmap.onMouseOut = handleMouseEvents;

   btn.onClick = openLink;
   btn.onMouseOver = handleMouseEvents;
   btn.onMouseOut = handleMouseEvents;


   stage.addChild(bitmap);
   stage.addChild(border);
   stage.addChild(btn);
  }

  function handleMouseEvents(event) {

   switch (event.type) {
    case "onMouseOver":
     document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';

     break;
    case "onMouseOut":
     document.body.style.cursor = 'default';

     break;
   }

  }

  function close(event) {
   enableCircles();
   createjs.Tween.get(popupElement).to({top: -90}, 350, createjs.Ease.backIn);
   createjs.Tween.get(background).to({opacity: 0}, 500, createjs.Ease.cubicInOut).call(onCloseComplete, null, this);

  }

  function onCloseComplete() {
   holder.onclick = null;
   holder.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }

  function openLink() {
   window.location.href = link;
  }


  function imageLoaded(event) {
   holder.onclick = close;
   bitmap.image = event.target;

   canvas.width = bitmap.image.width + 10;
   canvas.height = bitmap.image.height + 60;

   border.graphics.clear();
   border.graphics.beginStroke("#bcecfd");
   border.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2);
   border.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, bitmap.image.width, bitmap.image.height, 10);


   mask.graphics.clear();
   mask.graphics.beginFill("#ffffff");
   mask.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, bitmap.image.width, bitmap.image.height, 10);


   btn.x = Math.floor(canvas.width * .5);
   bitmap.x = border.x = mask.x = 5;
   bitmap.y = border.y = mask.y = 50;


   popupText.innerHTML = prizeDescription;
   popupText.style.fontSize = "32px";
   popupText.style.width = bitmap.image.width + "px";
   var textPos = bitmap.image.height + bitmap.y - popupText.clientHeight
   popupText.style.top = textPos + "px";


   textBackground.graphics.clear();

   textBackground.graphics.beginFill("#bcecfd");
   textBackground.alpha = .8;
   textBackground.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, bitmap.image.width, popupText.clientHeight);
   textBackground.x = bitmap.x;
   textBackground.y = bitmap.image.height + bitmap.y - popupText.clientHeight;
   textBackground.mask = mask;


   stage.addChild(textBackground);
   stage.update();

   canvas.style.top = "-20%";
   if (mobile) {
    popupElement.style.position = "absolute";
    var scale = 880 / canvas.width;
    var cHeight = scale * canvas.height;

    canvas.style.width = 800 + "px";
    canvas.style.height = cHeight + "px";
    canvas.style.marginTop = "120px";
    canvas.style.marginLeft = -400 + "px";

    popupText.style.marginLeft = (-400) + "px";
    popupText.style.fontSize = (Math.floor(32 * scale)) + "px";
    popupText.style.width = (800 - (20 * scale)) + "px";
    popupText.style.paddingLeft = popupText.style.paddingRight = (10 * scale) + "px";
    popupText.style.marginTop = "120px";
    popupText.style.top = ((bitmap.image.height + bitmap.y) * scale - popupText.clientHeight) + "px";


    createjs.Tween.get(popupElement).to({top: 0}, 300, createjs.Ease.backOut);//.call(hoverAnimComplete, null, this);
   } else {
    var pos = -Math.floor(canvas.width * .5);
    canvas.style.marginLeft = pos + "px";
    popupText.marginTop = "0px";
    popupText.style.marginLeft = (pos + 5) + "px";
    createjs.Tween.get(popupElement).to({top: 10}, 300, createjs.Ease.backOut);//.call(hoverAnimComplete, null, this);
   }
  }


  init();

  this.open = function (imageUrl, buttonLink) {
   var img = document.createElement("img");
   img.onload = imageLoaded;
   img.src = imageUrl;
   link = buttonLink;
   disableCircles();

   holder.style.visibility = "visible";
   background.style.opacity = 0;
   createjs.Tween.get(background).to({opacity: 1}, 1000, createjs.Ease.cubicOut);
  }


 }

 function getColors() {
  var array = new Array();
  array[0] = "#ffffff";
    array[1] = "#ffffff";
    array[2] = "#ffffff";
    array[3] = "#ffffff";
    array[4] = "#ffffff";
    array[5] = "#ffffff";
    array[6] = "#ffffff";
    array[7] = "#ffffff";
    array[8] = "#ffffff";
    array[9] = "#ffffff";
    array[10] = "#ffffff";
    array[11] = "#ffffff";
    array[12] = "#ffffff";
    array[13] = "#ffffff";
    array[14] = "#ffffff";
    array[15] = "#ffffff";
    array[16] = "#ffffff";
    array[17] = "#ffffff";
    array[18] = "#ffffff";
    array[19] = "#ffffff";
    array[20] = "#ffffff";
    array[21] = "#ffffff";
    array[22] = "#ffffff";
    array[23] = "#ffffff";

  return array;
 }

 //function getColors() {
 // var array = new Array();
 // array[0] = "#00bbff";
 // array[1] = "#fd6ec1";
 // array[2] = "#6fb431";
 // array[3] = "#6d5bbd";
 // array[4] = "#e3cbfd";
 // array[5] = "#fd6ec1";
 // array[6] = "#6fb431";
 // array[7] = "#fb3d2d";
 // array[8] = "#aece1d";
 // array[9] = "#ffb500";
 // array[10] = "#aece1d";
 // array[11] = "#00bbff";
 // array[12] = "#ffc4c1";
 // array[13] = "#fd6ec1";
 // array[14] = "#ff8a00";
 // array[15] = "#e3cbfd";
 // array[16] = "#ff8a00";
 // array[17] = "#6d5bbd";
 // array[18] = "#00bbff";
 // array[19] = "#ffb500";
 // array[20] = "#fd6ec1";
 // array[21] = "#6d5bbd";
 // array[22] = "#fb3d2d";
 // array[23] = "#00bbff";
 //
 // return array;
 //}

 function createMainSpritesheet(image) {
  var yVal = -Math.floor(elementFrames[0].height * .5) + 1;
  var numberOffset = 3;

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
   bitmap.sourceRect = elementFrames[i];
   bitmap.x = -Math.floor(elementFrames[i].width * .5);
   bitmap.y = yVal;

   switch (i) {
    case 1:
     bitmap.x += -2;
     break;
    case 2:
     bitmap.x += -1;
     break;
    case 3:
     bitmap.x += 1;
     break;
    case 4:
     bitmap.x += -2;
     break;
    case 5:
     bitmap.x += 1;
     break;
    case 6:
     bitmap.x += 1;
     break
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
     bitmap.x += 1;
     bitmap.y += 1;
     break;
   }

   var container = new createjs.Container();
   container.addChild(bitmap);
   numbers[i] = container;

  }

  for (i = 10; i < 29; i++) {
   var index = Math.floor(i / 10);
   var b1 = numbers[index].getChildAt(0).clone();
   b1.sourceRect = numbers[index].getChildAt(0).sourceRect;

   b1.x = -b1.sourceRect.width - numberOffset;
   index = i % 10;
   var b2 = numbers[index].getChildAt(0).clone();
   b2.sourceRect = numbers[index].getChildAt(0).sourceRect;
   b2.x = numberOffset;
   b2.y = yVal;


   var container = new createjs.Container();
   container.addChild(b1);
   container.addChild(b2);

   numbers[i] = container;

   switch (i) {
    case 10:
     b1.x -= 3;
     b2.x -= 3;
     b2.y += 1;
     break;
    case 11:
     b1.x -= 1;
     b2.x -= 1;

     break;
    case 12:
     b1.x -= 3;
     b2.x -= 3;
     break;
    case 13:
     b1.x -= 3;
     b2.x -= 3;
     b2.y += 1;
     break;
    case 14:
     b1.x -= 2;
     b2.x -= 4;
     b2.y += 1;
     break;
    case 15:
     b1.x -= 3;
     b2.x -= 3;
     b2.y += 1;
     break;
    case 16:
     b1.x -= 3;
     b2.x -= 3;
     b2.y += 1;
     break;
    case 17:
    case 18:
     b1.x -= 3;
     b2.x -= 3;
     break;
    case 19:
     b1.x -= 3;
     b2.x -= 3;
     b2.y += 1;
     break;
    case 20:
     b1.x += 1;
     b2.x += 0;
     b2.y += 1;
     break;
    case 21:
     b1.x += 3;
     b2.x += 3;
     break;
    case 22:
     b1.x += 1;
     b2.x += 1;
     break;
    case 23:
     b1.x += 1;
     b2.x += 1;
     b2.y += 1;
     break;
    case 24:
     b1.x += 1;
     b2.x += 0;
     b2.y += 1;
     break;
   }

  }
  tempPresent = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
  tempPresent.sourceRect = elementFrames[15];
  tempPresent.regX = tempPresent.regY = 55;

 }


 function createFrames() {
  var array = new Array();
  //numbers
  array[0] = new createjs.Rectangle(226, 0, 28, 46);
  array[1] = new createjs.Rectangle(1, 0, 19, 46);
  array[2] = new createjs.Rectangle(19, 0, 25, 46);
  array[3] = new createjs.Rectangle(45, 0, 26, 46);
  array[4] = new createjs.Rectangle(70, 0, 26, 46);
  array[5] = new createjs.Rectangle(98, 0, 25, 46);
  array[6] = new createjs.Rectangle(124, 0, 25, 46);
  array[7] = new createjs.Rectangle(149, 0, 26, 46);
  array[8] = new createjs.Rectangle(175, 0, 23, 46);   
  array[9] = new createjs.Rectangle(199, 0, 26, 46);
  //star
  array[10] = new createjs.Rectangle(262, 8, 137, 137);
  //click to enter16,92,69,44
  array[11] = new createjs.Rectangle(16, 92, 69, 44);
  //my family club8,52,192,33
  array[12] = new createjs.Rectangle(8, 52, 192, 33);
  //advent calendar2,138,397,94
  array[13] = new createjs.Rectangle(2, 138, 397, 94);
  //text0,239,459,65
  array[14] = new createjs.Rectangle(0, 239, 459, 65);
  //present
  array[15] = new createjs.Rectangle(405, 0, 110, 110);
  return array;
 }

 function hexToR(h) {
  return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(0, 2), 16)
 }
 function hexToG(h) {
  return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(2, 4), 16)
 }
 function hexToB(h) {
  return parseInt((cutHex(h)).substring(4, 6), 16)
 }
 function cutHex(h) {
  return (h.charAt(0) == "#") ? h.substring(1, 7) : h
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.  Stray characters...!

This is what happens when you have been looking at the code too long!